# Paraview create line segments from CSV with "width" data

Tags: python, graph, paraview, line-segment

I want to create line segments in Paraview. The format of my input data for each line segment is as:
x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,width
I have tried using "Line" command like:

```
    for i in range(600):
      l = Line(Point1=(uniform(0,100),uniform(0,100),0),Point2=(uniform(0,100),uniform(0,100),0))
```

But, I can't find a way to specify the width to each line segment.
Your help will be much appreciated.
Best Regards,
Hamid Rajabi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Line object does not know about the `width`. It is only a list of connected points. The `width` is a parameter of the representation. You can try something like that:

```
# get active view
renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')

for i in range(600):
  l = Line(Point1=(uniform(0,100),uniform(0,100),0),Point2=(uniform(0,100),uniform(0,100),0))
  # get display properties
  line1Display = GetDisplayProperties(l, view=renderView1)

  # Properties modified on line1Display
  line1Display.LineWidth = 4.0
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your answer. However, since I am new to Paraview, I just faced two new problems:
1- How can I display all lines as "tubes" and all points as "spheres"
2- The number of my data is big and it seems to take the Paraview a long time to show all the lines.
Again, thank you very much for your answer. Although, it's not easy to find help online in these matters, it was complete.

Comment: If you know how to use the GUI of ParaView, try the `Tool / Python Trace`. It will record the action you perform in the interface and dump it as a python script. It is very handful to discover the API.

Comment: I am using Paraview 5.8.1 and it seems there is not such an option in the <Tool> section. All in all it would be much more convenient for me to find a "scripting" solution for this.
How can I do the same thing( plotting line segments with specific width for each) with a "vtk" code?

Comment: My bad, it is `Tools / Start Trace` menu